# Any way to quickly (drag and drop) reorder tasks in Redmine?

Tags: memory-management, project, redmine, priority-queue, redmine-plugins

We're using Redmine to log and track all of our tasks, bugs, and features. We have a one month release cycle and it's important to ensure that the order of the items in Redmine corresponds to the relative priority of each item, so that people are not working on less important stuff.

Currently to achieve this we created a custom field in Redmine called 'rank' and assigned each items a integer from 1-1000. This works initially but re-ranking items and reordering is just painful because the same item ends up being edited many times to get it in the correct place on the priority list. Is there any way to be able to drag and drop items to reorder them? I doubt we have a unique requirement, there must be some way other people are doing this??

Thanks for the help in advance,
Max

Comment: So you're saying that every item is ranked in relation to every other, and not put into buckets of 'High' 'Medium' 'Low' or something similar?  I looked here http://www.redmine.org/plugins and didn't find anything that matched what you describe.  Maybe a new plugin is called for?

Comment: Exactly. We have a lot of bugs/tasks so every priority category (i.e. High, Medium) has more than 50 items in it - we need to be able to communicate priority on those so lower priority items are left for last

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the Stuff To Do plugin from Eric Davis?  It may be close to what you're looking for -

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/PluginStuffToDo

https://github.com/edavis10/redmine-stuff-to-do-plugin

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there is an existing plugin to do this. It has been raised on the Redmine forums, but nothing seems to have come of it:

http://www.redmine.org/issues/9183

Answer (score 0):

Thats right, There is no existing plugin to do that. Stuff_to_do is user-level organization of tasks assigned to him and drag-and-drop to recoorganize the tasks from/to 'current working list', 'recommended list of tasks' and 'available list of tasks'.

I kinda feel there should be an alternative to your requirement. Why should we rank the tasks? We should probably conduct scrum/stand-ups and assign list of tasks to each person and reorganize the order in the stuff_to_do plugin so that the developer checks off the tasks in his list.

Also you can group the related tasks together using 'Related Tasks' option in each issue. Add an issue to be a 'follower'/'predecessor' to an other issue.

Use better reporting using 'custom queries'

Use Redmine_whining plugin to remind developers.

Answer (score -3):

These are just my view based on the exposure I got in the area of Agile Product Management and Redmine plugins